# SQL Days before end of the month

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have got table with transactions, looking like:

```
+----+--------------+----------------+------+
| ID |  OrderDate   |  DeliveryDate  |  EUR |
+----+--------------+----------------+------+
| 1  | 2015-02-21   |  2015-02-25    | 100  |
| 2  | 2015-03-01   |  2015-03-14    | 110  |
| 3  | 2015-03-01   |  2015-03-17    |  90  |
| 4  | 2015-03-10   |  2015-03-20    | 250  |
| 5  | 2015-03-31   |  2015-03-31    | 350  |
+----+--------------+----------------+------+
```

ANd I need to get sum of revenue and number of orders (COUNT of IDs) based on Days before the end of the month when order gets delivered.

```
SELECT datediff(day, OrderDate, CAST(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,0,getdate()+1,0)-1) as Date) as DBEOM, SUM(EUR) as Rev, COUNT(ID) as NumberOfOrders

FROM transactions
WHERE MONTH(DeliveryDate) = 3 AND YEAR(DeliveryDate) = 2015

GROUP BY datediff(day, OrderDate, CAST(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,0,getdate()+1,0)-1) as Date) as DBEOM
ORDER BY 1
```

The result in this case would be like:

```
+-----+-----+----------------+
|DBEOM| Rev | NumberOfOrders |
+-----+-----+----------------+
|   0 | 350 |              1 |
|  21 | 250 |              1 |
|  30 | 200 |              2 |
+-----+-----+----------------+
```

This is done in `SQL 2008`, so I can't simply use `EOMONTH`. I have tried, what is above, but i am getting 
ERROR -

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The `datediff` function
>   requires 3 argument(s).

Many thanks in advance for advice!

Comment: You have 4 parameter for `DATEDIFF`

Comment: I was very confused by your expected results and the sentence "based on Days before the end of the month when order gets delivered" until I realised that what you've shown is based on `OrderDate` rather than `DeliveryDate` which is what I would have expected for "when order gets delivered"

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found get the last day of the month with more primitive functions is to get the first day of the next month and then subtract a day.

I'm not a TSQL guy so this syntax likely won't be correct but you need something more like

DATEADD(day, DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(year, DATEADD(month,1,getdate()), DATEPART(month, DATEADD(month,1,getdate()), 1), -1)

Comment: OP has already indicated that they're on 2008 so `DATEFROMPARTS` isn't available. Also, there are far simpler formulas for computing the last day of the current month than what you've shown, e.g. `DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',getdate()),'20010131')`

Comment: Ah, well, like I said I'm not a TSQL guy, I didn't realize something as basic as DATEFROMPART wouldn't be available.    Your formula for getting the last day of the month is interesting... but is it really simpler?  I have to admit I prefer mine, just because it's a little more transparent and takes less brain power to understand what it's doing.

Comment: Damien, this is working well. I have just changed getdate() to DeliveryDate   as I need to do this for data across multiple month (the aim is to get kind of growth charts for each month ...).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT datediff(day,
              OrderDate,
              dateadd(DAY,
                      -1,
                      dateadd(MONTH,
                              1,
                              dateadd(DAY,
                                      1-day(DeliveryDate),
                                      DeliveryDate
                                     )
                             )
                     )
             ) as DBEOM, SUM(EUR) as Rev, COUNT(ID) as NumberOfOrders

FROM t
WHERE MONTH(DeliveryDate) = 3 AND YEAR(DeliveryDate) = 2015

GROUP BY datediff(day,
              OrderDate,
              dateadd(DAY,
                      -1,
                      dateadd(MONTH,
                              1,
                              dateadd(DAY,
                                      1-day(DeliveryDate),
                                      DeliveryDate
                                     )
                             )
                     )
             )
ORDER BY 1
```

[sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fe35d/4/0)

Comment: I am getting: ERROR - [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function.

Comment: Sorry, missing arguments order, when sqlFiddle was down.